# Problem using Appmobi XDK!

Tags: html

plz anyone can tell me how to open our project at Appmobi XDK. i am facing a problem that i have install it but its not allow me to open projects. when i tried to open my project a message comes unable to open a project.

now i need your help guys.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing you need to do is to go to xdk.appmobi.com (in google chrome) and download/install our xdk. (Need Java installed also)
During the install you will need to set a default appmobi directory. This is where your app files will be stored.

Create a new app from within the XDK. You can then click the edit the source code button in the tool bar to edit your code. Here you can update the file with your own code.

You can check out a video that explains the xdk at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWV8kOJlGmc  Some things might have changed visually with the current version of the XDK, but essentially its the same.

Some things have changed/moved around the screen since we made the video, but essentially its functionally the same.
Check it out as it will give you tips/how To's to using the XDK.

Also, posting in our forums (forums.appmobi.com) will get your questions answered sooner!